# I want to automate axes subplot using for loop rather than defining each subset

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, function, syntax-error

I created scatter plot using following code (Code 1). It works fine. My question is about code2. Since, I want to create multiple plots, I am interesting in using for loop to create them rather then writing each. I wrote for loop code (code 2) but it gives an error. Please help me with code 2.

code1

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig,(ax1,ax2,ax3)=plt.subplots(3,1,figsize=(5,10))
ax1.scatter(norm_reviews["Fandango_Ratingvalue"],norm_reviews["RT_user_norm"])
ax1.set_xlabel("Fandango")
ax1.set_ylabel("Rotten Tomatoes")
ax1.set_xlim(0,5)
ax1.set_ylim(0,5)
ax2.scatter(norm_reviews["Fandango_Ratingvalue"],norm_reviews["Metacritic_user_nom"])
ax2.set_xlabel("Fandango")
ax2.set_ylabel("Metacritic")
ax2.set_xlim(0,5)
ax2.set_ylim(0,5)
ax3.scatter(norm_reviews["Fandango_Ratingvalue"],norm_reviews["IMDB_norm"])
ax3.set_xlabel("Fandango")
ax3.set_ylabel("IMDB")
ax3.set_xlim(0,5)
ax3.set_ylim(0,5)
plt.show()
```

code2:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
for i in range(3):
    fig,ax(i) = plt.figure(3,1,i,figsize=(5,10))    
    x_label="Fandango"
    y_label=["RT_user_norm","Metacritic_user_nom","IMDB_norm"]
    ax(i).scatter(norm_reviews[x_label],norm_reviews[y_label[i]])
    ax(i).set_xlim(0,5)
    ax(i).set_ylim(0,5)
    ax(i).set_xlabel(x_label)
    ax(i).set_ylabel(y_label[i])
plt.show()
```

Comment: `range(3)` to `range(1, 4)`

Comment: can you elaborate on it? If possible, would you be willing to share how to write in code?

Answer (score 1):

range(3) will give you 0, 1, 2. You can not index a subplot from zero.

You can use this basic structure :

```py
plt.figure()
for i in range(3):
    plt.subplot(3,1,i+1)
    plt.plot([1,2], [3,4])
plt.show()
```

Other possibility :

```py
fig, axs = plt.subplots(3, 1, sharex=True)
for i in range(3):
    axs[i].plot([0, 1], [2, 3])
plt.show()
```

Comment: After trying above syntax, I get ValueError: sharex [1] must be one of ['all', 'row', 'col', 'none']

Comment: I updated my answer with another way to use subplots.